# Chrome Extension Message Passing - Code included

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-extension

I have a contentscript called file.js that creates variable "found". I want to send the values of varibale "found" to a textbox in popup.html

In file.js (I know varible found is working, tested using an alert).

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({foundlinks: found}, function(response) {
 console.log(response);
});
```

In Popup.html:

```
function pulllinks(){

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    document.getElementById("box").value = request.foundlinks;

  sendResponse({});
});
```

And on the form in popup.html:

```
<input type = "button" onclick="pulllinks();" name = "box" id="box" value = "Grab Links From Page"  />
```

However, its not doing anything. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sending requests in the opposite direction - from popup to content script:

**popup.html:**

```
function pulllinks(){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {cmd: "findLinks"}, function(response) {
            document.getElementById("box").value = response.foundlinks;
        });
    });

}
```

**file.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "findLinks") {
        //calculate "found" value and send it back
        sendResponse({foundlinks: found});

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your listener for `onRequest` should exist from the start, so move it outside of the `pulllinks` function. Secondly, how are you making sure that your `sendRequest` is being fired while the popup is open?

Comment: Ok so move the function pulllinks to the top and remove the function and keep the code. No idea what you mean by the second part.

Comment: I meant, for the "second part" how are you making sure that your content script is sending the request *while* your popup is open?

Comment: The thing is I have no idea how these requests work so I assumed by running the function when the button was clicked it would initiate the messaging.

Comment: Nurp. It works like this: 1.) 'Sender' sends out a request, 2.) 'Receiver' receives the request. The process is almost instantaneous, and the 'Receiver' has to exist **at the time of sending** for it to receive the message.